# Understanding backpressure in webflux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am new to Reactive/Webflux, and am trying to understand backpressure in Webflux. I have the following controller. Our application takes in a JSON request for search, and responds back with a flux stream.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/search",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<ResponseContainer> getItineraries(@RequestBody SearchRequest searchRequest){

        return searchService
              .convertToFlux(searchRequest)
              .map(<do some transformations>)
              .map(<WebClientRequestsDownstream>)
              .map(<aggregrate>);
    }
```

Is backpressure applied for an instance of a stream or for all instances as a whole? i.e. If I have a stream where requests are coming in via webflux controller, will slow down in previous requests apply back-pressure to future requests? Or will backpressure be applied only because of the slowdown in an active flux stream based on the slowdown in the currently active request?

Comment: did you read the official documentation before you asked? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_on_backpressure_and_ways_to_reshape_requests

Comment: @ThomasAndolf yes I did, this was unclear.

Comment: here you can read more about backpressure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296097/are-subscribers-in-spring-reactor-unbounded-by-default https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

Comment: @ThomasAndolf- thanks for the link, my question is a little specific, is backpressure applied for an instance of the stream or for all instances as a whole..I understand conceptually what backpressure is

Comment: your question is rather strange, if you understand the concept you understand that each step in the chain will request for the next item, and everyone is affected of the same chain.

Comment: yes but based on that each chain would be considered separately, so if a single request is slow it will not impact other requests in a webflux, because each of them is a new stream instance?

Answer (score 1):

A `Flux` is a `Publisher`, which is connected to a "request" by handling a `Subscription` to a `Subscriber`. Each `Subscriber` gets its own `Subscription`, so you can see that relationship as the materialization of an individual request, whereas the `Publisher` is more like the endpoint (if we simplify and only consider cold publishers, ie. publishers that generate a dedicated dataset to each subscriber).

Backpressure is driven by the `Subscriber` calling `Subscription#request`, so it is separated at the level of each request.