# Designing waiting publisher on backpressure - reactive progamming

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

I use `projectreactor` to develop in `reactive` manner in Java my personal project. Let's see on the picture below:

[image: gn]

In my design, there are some publisher threads that want to publish messages to the flux or via flux and there are some subscribers that processes messages. And now, it is possible that subscribers will be too slow. Therefore I need some backpressure mechanism. And I know that there are some backpressure strategies but no strategy meets my expectations. I want my publisher just block (wait) until message buffer is (nearly) empty.

So, how to implement it in reactive manner?

Comment: Hmm... reactive programming and blocking concepts normally do not mix well. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Comment: Yes, because I cannot buffer / drop / skip elements from stream. It seems to be stupid: you can use backpressure but only solution is to drop elements.

Comment: You get the desired behavior automatically if your publisher is a cold source.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi, could you tell me more?

Comment: @Gilgamesz check out this answer, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57298393/6051176

Comment: Also, if you have some initial code you can share, it might be easier to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi, thanks. `blockLast` was missing in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel activities can be of 2 kinds: threads and actors (also called asynchronous procedures). They differ in the way how they communicate. Flux is a communication object for actors. It does not fit to connect threads. Threads are well connected with BlockingQueue.

Comment: So, how to design it using actors?

Comment: then you have to reimplement Publishers and Subscribers as actors, not threads. It is a complex task. Replacing Flux with BlockingQueue is much simpler.