# How to log error to DB and resume execution in project reactor?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I want to log an error to a mongo db collection and continue with the error propagation in the pipeline. How can I do that in project reactor?

Current code makes use of an extractor(`Mono.block()`), which to my knowledge, is not advised to use. This is what current code looks like:

```
        testMono.doOnError(throwable -> {
            var errorObject = ErrorObject.builder()
                    .message(throwable.getLocalizedMessage())
                    .className(throwable.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .build();
            errorMessageRepository.save(errorObject).block();
        })
```

Is this correct way to do it or should I use a `Mono.subscribe()` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using `block()`.

If you need a *fire-and-forget* call you could use `subscribe()`:

```java
 testMono.doOnError(throwable -> {
            var errorObject = ErrorObject.builder()
                    .message(throwable.getLocalizedMessage())
                    .className(throwable.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .build();
            errorMessageRepository.save(errorObject).subscribe();
        })
```

Note that in that case, you lose backpressure support.

Alternatively, you could use `onErrorResume` operator like this:

```java
testMono.onErrorResume(throwable -> {
    var errorObject = ErrorObject.builder()
            .message(throwable.getLocalizedMessage())
            .className(throwable.getClass().getSimpleName())
            .build();
    return errorMessageRepository.save(errorObject).then(Mono.error(throwable)));
});
```

That way, `then` operator replays the error as is.

Comment: Just to confirm. Does this code propagates the same error in the pipeline after the save to db operation completion ?

Comment: Yes, `then` operator replays the error as is.

Comment: How could one loose back pressure support using the fire-and-forget method mentioned above? Could you please provide any article or document for me to read further on this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57569541/8909235 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57296097/how-does-backpressure-work-in-project-reactor