# What is the difference between ProjectReactor.io vs Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

What is the difference between **ProjectReactor.io** vs **Spring WebFlux**?

I've read the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html and https://projectreactor.io/, for me both are very similar to each other. I am interested to learn the highlights on this.

Comment: Spring WebFlux is using ProjectRector.io, so the link between them is that WebFlux depends on ProjectRector

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are on different abstraction level, so they can't really be compared as such.

**Project Reactor** is a general purpose reactive library. Similarly to RxJava, it is based on the [reactive-streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) specification. It is like Java 8 `Stream` and `Optional`, except it has support for asynchronous programming, error handling is built-in, supports [backpressure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57298393/6051176) and has a large number of operators (`map`, `filter` and many more).

**Spring Webflux** is a framework to create web services using reactive libraries. Its main goal is to ensure high scalability with low resource usage (i.e. small number of threads). Under the hood it uses Project Reactor, however, you can also use it with RxJava (or any other reactive-streams implementation) and it works well even with Kotlin Coroutines.